# Office online Server does't work in Sharepoint Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, windows-server-2012-r2, office-online-server

I am a developer and I was entrusted with the administration of windows servers (windows server 2012 r2), first experience elsewhere.
I have three (03) windows 2012 R2 servers:
DC: domain controller
SP: Sharepoint server 2016
OOS: Office Online Server 2016 (Hypper-V on SP Server)

I was able to configure both servers in HTTP and everything worked perfectly because we were testing regime.

[image]

But in production it was necessary to use the HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP (recommended by Microsoft). For this fact, I have therefore taken the configurations for adaptation with the HTTPS protocol, but I get errors

[image]

Who has encountered this problem below? I need yours helps please.

Comment: We can't help you with the information supplied. Does this happen with Word and Excel documents, as well? Did you collect ULS logs from both SharePoint and OOS when you opened this? Update your question with those additional details so we can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

affter troubleshooting:
Analyzed event logs of SharePoint and OWA servers and found nothing useful. Logged in to the Office Web Apps server and Analysed the latest log file from "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Data\Logs\ULS" location.

[image]

pro_sp is name of SharePoint server

Comment: In my OOS server there is no "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Data\Logs\ULS" path. There is no C:\ProgramData. It is a win2019 server. Is it make any different?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set both servers to use TLS 1.2 only, 
I had a similar problem with my Office Online Server 2018 (NOV) and Exchange Server 2019, turned out for some reasons Exchange Can't automatically negotiate the correct Encryption Protocol and use TLS 1.2 for inter servers communications. (though it was claimed otherwise in documents)

Check:
[Discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37bc46c3-3996-4ec7-be8a-fb63ac78023c/office-online-server-nov-2018-iso?forum=OfficeOnlineServer)

You need to set the following registry keys on both (all) machines to enable TLS 1.2:

Disable TLS 1.0

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Disable TLS 1.1:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Disable SSL 2.0:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Disable SSL 3.0

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Enable TLS 1.2:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
```

Enable Strong Encryption .NETFRAMWORK

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```